# Bubble Sorting not working

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, bubble-sort

I was working with the Bubble sorting algorithm and implemented it on code. The objective is to sort an integer array of size N using bubble sorting , count the number of data comparisons and the number of data movements , where data comparisons are the amount of times the integer are compared and data movements are the amount of the integers swap places . Finally we only calculate the time taken to execute the sorting. Now, the issue is when the value of N is a large number say 1000 / 10000 /20000 etc. for the first 30-50 test cases the bubble sorting works but after that , it is seen that a  many smaller numbers have not been sorted. One more thing to keep in mind is that I assigned the values of the elements of the array to random numbers.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Bubblesort {
public static long DC;
public static long DM;

public static int[] BBSort(int arr[],int n) {
    int K,t,tmp;

    long Data_comp=0,Data_move=0;

    K = n;
    while(K!=0)
    {
        t = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < K-1; i++) {

            if(arr[i]>arr[i+1])
            {
               tmp = arr[i];
               arr[i] = arr[i+1];
               arr[i+1] = tmp;
               t = i;
               Data_move++;
            }
            Data_comp++;
        }

        K = t;
    }
    DC = Data_comp;
    DM = Data_move;
  return arr;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random r = new Random();
    int N;
    N = sc.nextInt();
    int a[];
    a = new int[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
          a[i]=r.nextInt(10000);
    }
    long StartTime,EndTime;
    long Totaltime;
    StartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    BBSort(a, N);
    EndTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Totaltime = EndTime - StartTime;

    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        System.out.println(a[j]);
    }
    System.out.println("Time taken for sorting = "+Totaltime);
    System.out.println("Number of data comparisons = "+DC );
    System.out.println("Number of data movement = "+3*DM);


}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the way you use the variable t. Just remove it and use K-- at the end of each run and it will solve your issue.

```
public static int[] BBSort(int arr[],int n) {
    int K,tmp;

    long Data_comp=0,Data_move=0;

    K = n;
    while(K!=0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < K-1; i++) {

            if(arr[i]>arr[i+1])
            {
               tmp = arr[i];
               arr[i] = arr[i+1];
               arr[i+1] = tmp;
               Data_move++;
            }
            Data_comp++;
        }

        K--;
    }
    DC = Data_comp;
    DM = Data_move;
  return arr;
}
```

Comment: The code worked , I removed the variable t and the sorting works out fine . Now can you just give me an explanation on why the variable "t" was creating the issue.

Comment: Josh Heaps on the answer bellow pretty much answers it. You cannot skip some comparisons. 

By only looping up to the last index where numbers have been swapped (variable  t) you change the bubble sort algorithm and allow it to skip some numbers which are ordered in regards of their direct neighbours but are not ordered in your whole set of data.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I believe I have found your problem.

So, in a bubble sort, the program needs to run through every number, every time. If the program doesn't do this, you create opportunities for numbers to find their way into the wrong spot, and be trapped there.

In your function `BBSort` Your program is setting the amount of times run the for loop runs to the last index there was a swap. In that situation, you may have two numbers that are in the right order, by themselves, at the end. I.E. Take this list: {1, 2, 9, 5, 6, 10} On this array, the code would recognize wherever the two numbers were properly sorted. This means, when it gets to 6 and 10, it says, "Okay, those two are sorted" and doesn't touch the 6 ever again. Here is some pseudocode for a bubble sort that I've made and works:

```
for i = 0 ; i < number of items in array; i++{
    for j = 0; j < number of items in array; j++{
        if (list[j] < list[j+1])
            swap list[j] with list[j+1];
    }
}
```

I hope that you've found this helpful and that everything works out!